# re render specific component on each route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router-dom

I've been looking around to find a solution and couldn't find anything.
All results that came from searching this was on how to avoid other components re rendering .

Basically as the title says I am trying to make a component which is outside the routes to re render on each route change .
This component returning a notification if history object has a specific state .
Right now this component work as it should, the only problem is that it's only rendered once so it wont search to see if history object has been changed and the notification wont happend .

This is my App :

```js
const App = () => {
    return(
        <Router history={history}>
            <NotificationComponent>
                {searchSystemNotification()}
            </NotificationComponent>
            <img id="background-shape" src={shape} alt="" />
            <Header />
            <Routes />
            <Footer />
        </Router>
    )
}
```

This is the function that runs inside the notification component to see if history object has the specific state it's looking for :

```js
const searchSystemNotification = () => {
  if(typeof history.location.state !== 'undefined'){
    if(history.location.state.hasOwnProperty('message')){
      let systemNotification = history.location.state.message;
      
      // Delete message after showing it
      let state = history.location.state;
      delete state.message;
      history.replace({ ...history.location, state });

      return(
        <Message type={systemNotification.type} text={systemNotification.text} />
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Basically all i need is to re render "NotificationComponent" on each route change to ofcourse return the "Message" component if the state exists .

Comment: You can use the `useHistory` hook in `NotificationComponent` or its child to subscribe to changes in `history`.

Answer (score 0):

#### useHistory

You can use the [`useHistory` hook](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) anywhere inside your `Router` to subscribe to changes in its `history`.

I don't know what your `NotificationComponent` looks like.  One possibility is to call `useHistory` in the `NotificationComponent` and define its child as a function of history.

Based on what I'm seeing here, the most straight-forward thing to do is to refactor `searchSystemNotification()` into a function component and call `useHistory` there.  The component will either render a `Message` or `null`.

```
const SearchSystemNotification = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  if(typeof history.location.state === 'object'){
    if(history.location.state.hasOwnProperty('message')){
      // let's use destructuring instead of `delete`
      const {message, ...rest} = {history.location.state};
      // pass all values other than message
      history.replace({ ...history.location, state: rest });

      return(
        <Message type={message.type} text={message.text} />
      )
    }
  }
  // if we aren't rendering a message then return null
  return null;
}
```

#### Removing Message

We have a big problem with the above code.  Our component will re-render with the new value of `history` every time that history changes.  But inside the hook **we are changing `history`** by removing the `message` from the `state`.  So the message will show for a moment and then immediately disappear as our component re-renders in response to the changes that it made.

We want to either A) just keep the message in the history or B) remove the message only in response to user action, like clicking an "x" on the message.

For B), try this:

```
const SearchSystemNotification = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  if(typeof history.location.state === 'object'){
    if(history.location.state.hasOwnProperty('message')){
      // let's use destructuring instead of `delete`
      const {message, ...rest} = history.location.state;
      const onClickClose = () => {
        history.replace({ ...history.location, state: rest });
      }

      return(
        <Message type={message.type} text={message.text} onClickClose={onClickClose} />
      )
    }
  }
  // if we aren't rendering a message then return null
  return null;
}
```

#### Edit: useLocation

It turns out we need to use `useLocation` in order to reload on location changes.  We can combine this with `useHistory` to handle closing the message like this:

```
const SearchSystemNotification = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();

  if (typeof location.state === "object") {
    if (location.state.hasOwnProperty("message")) {
      // let's use destructuring instead of `delete`
      const { message, ...rest } = location.state;
      const onClickClose = () => {
        history.replace({ ...history.location, state: rest });
      };

      return (
        <Message
          type={message.type}
          text={message.text}
          onClickClose={onClickClose}
        />
      );
    }
  }
  // if we aren't rendering a message then return null
  return null;
};
```

Alternatively, we can avoid making changes to history by keeping the `message` in the history and having the `Message` component render conditionally based on its own internal state.  We can hide it based on a user click of an `"X"` or based on a timeout.

```
const SearchSystemNotification = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  if (typeof location.state === "object") {
    if (location.state.hasOwnProperty("message")) {
      return (
        <Message
          {...location.state.message}
        />
      );
    }
  }
  // if we aren't rendering a message then return null
  return null;
};
```

Comment: Hay @Linda Paiste, Thank you for your answer. I might have been un clear with my question or mabey i have missed something in your answer but that's unlikely. What i am trying to do is to show a message on "history.push". eg when a client submit some data he's being redirected using history.push. since the "SearchSystemNotification" component is not a child of the path redirect then it wont re render even if the history changes. I've tried to use the code that you've provided and the result was the same as i had, after the redirection the message wont show until i refresh the page .

Comment: Can you post a CodeSandbox? I am not understanding the setup.  Maybe the issue is that you are passing a custom `history` object as a prop to your `Router`.  Is there a reason that you are doing that?

Comment: I've written a [short version](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-wing-4hzo8?file=/src/SearchSystemNotification.jsx) . try the button with "useHistory" hook, watch the console. see how it wont log again(wont render) only once when application is loaded. also while writing the shortend version i've find out that using the "useLocation" hook does what i want . So i found my solution . Also here is a [video](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AshPXnJ8kM_rh4FtcBGQ04yaMQM9qw?e=FubsyM) . Thanks !

Comment: Look like we need to combine the two hooks: `useLocation` to subscribe to the location and `useHistory` to clear the message.  https://codesandbox.io/s/show-message-on-redirect-pdbl7?file=/src/message.jsx

Comment: Re: user interface, you can do an overlay like https://ant.design/components/message/ or https://ant.design/components/notification/ with a timeout.  I was picturing something inline with an "X" like this https://ant.design/components/alert/